# Get request with body ? angular

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, http

angular service

```
  public extractUsername(token) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('token', token);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/extractUsername', {headers});
  }
```

spring boot method

```
@GetMapping("/extractUsername")
public String extractUsername(@RequestBody(required=false) TokenRequest tokenRequest)  {
    String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(tokenRequest.getToken());
    return username;
}
```

I cannot get token with this angular request

So my question is can i use requestbody method with get request? In postman it work as it should, if it is possible how should angular service look? 
Im new to angular thanks for response.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: But when i make spring PostMapping and change get to post in angular, in postman it still works but when i try to access it with angular it is giving me same error

Comment: What is the error in developer console network tab ?

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot, and when i change it to postmapping it is giving same error but with this message "JWT String argument cannot be null or empty."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Angular side, the header value is not being set. You need to assign the set or append result back to the variable:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token', token);
```

In the controller, you have to extract the header from the request. In Spring, you can do this by using the @RequestHeader annotation:

```
@GetMapping("/extractUsername")
public String extractUsername(@RequestHeader(value="token") String token)  {
    String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(token);
    return username;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also inject HttpServletRequest into the method and extract it from the request:

```
@GetMapping("/extractUsername")
public String extractUsername(HttpServletRequest request)  {
    String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(request.getHeader("token"));
    return username;
}
```